# How to replace price only inside of a span with special Arabic characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have span that returns text and a price.

I have read a few tutorials and so far I am about 80% done.

What I eventually want do:

1. Dom is triggered
2. Store price only inside of integer
3. Multiply and Apply tax (1.05%)
4. Update the price only and leave
   text intact

JS so far:

```
var price = jQuery('span').text().replace(/[^\d\.]*/g, '');
price = parseFloat(price).toFixed(2) * 1.05;
```

But Saudi and UAE have special characters such as `٬` and `٫` are mixed on decimals + other strange characaters.

All I want to update is the price - not the text. But there are many combinations I need to match:

```
<span>AED 698.99</span> = 733.93
<span>698.99 AED</span> = 733.93

<span>AED 1,167.00</span> = 1225.35
<span>1,167.00 AED</span> = 1225.35

<span>1٬193٫00 درهم</span> = 1252.65
<span>درهم 1٬193٫00</span> = 1252.65

<span>424٫00 درهم</span> = 445.2
<span>درهم 424٫00</span> = 445.2

<span>AED 15,592.00</span> = 16371.6
<span>15,592.00 AED</span> = 16371.6

<span>15٬592٫00 درهم</span> = 16371.6
<span>درهم 15٬592٫00</span> = 16371.6
```

It should ideally return as above.

Comment: Can't you add the `data-price` attribute as `<span data-price="689.99">AED 698.99</span>` and make your own life easier?

Comment: You can test it using `/[^a-z0-9,.]/i`

Comment: @gurvinder372 has the best solution here - add the plain, unformatted price as a `data` attribute which you can use in any calculation you need: `<span data-price="1193.00">1٬193٫00درهم</span>`

Comment: I cannot manipulate the HTML; I already had this aspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('span').each(function(index, span ){
    var price = $(span).text()
        .replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    var price = parseFloat(price).toFixed(2) * 1.05;
    $(span).text(price/100);

}) ;
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j1Lhyss0/2/

Comment: This is a good solution but it removes the text. I only want to update the price

Comment: I think I will accept this and try to add and modify based on your answer to see if I can hack around that first comma.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to add an attribute which you can later use for calculation

```
<span data-price="689.99">AED 698.99</span>
```

However, if you can't do it, then you can match all *digits* `\d` and *dot* `.` and then `join` them

```
var getNum = (str) =>  Number((str.match(/\d|\./g) || [0]).join( "" ));
```

**Demo**

```js
var getNum = (str) =>  Number((str.match(/\d|\./g) || [0]).join( "" ));

console.log( getNum( "AED 698.99" ) );
console.log( getNum( "698.99 AED" ) );
console.log( getNum( "AED 1,167.00" ) );
console.log( getNum( "AED 15,592.00" ) );
```

**And finally** multiple them by `1.05`

```
var final = getNum( str ) * 1.05;
```

Comment: This does not work with `15٬592٫00 درهم` where it returns `1559200` and the numbers should ideally return correctly otherwise customer complaints

Comment: what is the number in that text? It is impossible to copy also somehow :)

Comment: Even this `15٬592٫00 دره does not work` it is just the way Arabic is rendered.